# why does my TimeOffset modifier not work after rendered?

Tags: modifiers, grease-pencil

[image]I made an animation with the TimeOffset modifier in the grease-pencil.It can loop in the blender.But when it output ,my TimeOffset doesn't loop anymore.The Loop only plays once when rendered.

Comment: please，help！！！！

Comment: I also had the same problem... but it was fixed in Blender 2.93 (beta)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue. The TimeOffset modifier is completely functional during renders in Blender 2.91. It looks like the discrepancy is limited to Blender 2.92 which means that if you use one of the earlier versions from this link, it should work. https://download.blender.org/release/. Hopefully this bug will be fixed in version 2.93

Comment: i can confirm that it works fine in 2.93 alpha